# Values of a dict in a dropdown django

Tags: python, ajax, django, drop-down-menu

My models.py is as follows:

```
class SellerMarketplaces(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID',primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
seller_id = models.ForeignKey('Sellerdetails',db_column='Seller_ID')  # Field name made lowercase.
mk_id = models.ForeignKey('Marketplace',db_column='Mk_ID')  # Field name made lowercase.
username = models.CharField(db_column='Username', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

I have the following code in my views

```
def marketplaces(request):  

seller = request.GET.get('seller', '')
allmarketplaces = SellerMarketplaces.objects.filter(seller_id = seller).values('mk_id__marketplace')
print allmarketplaces
```

through which I'm getting the following output:

```
[{'mk_id__marketplace': u'Flipkart'}, {'mk_id__marketplace': u'Snapdeal'}]
```

I want to display the values i.e., Flipkart and Snapdeal in a dropdown but I'm unable to access the values, when I'm writing

```
print allmarketplaces.values()
```

it's giving me

```
 [{'username': u'mail@fields.com', u'seller_id_id': 1L, u'mk_id_id': 1L, 'id': 1L}, {'username': u'mail@fields.com', u'seller_id_id': 1L, u'mk_id_id': 2L, 'id': 2L}]
```

how can i access the values (Flipkart & Snapdeal)?

Comment: indent your code properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
>>> allmarketplaces = SellerMarketplaces.objects.filter(seller_id=seller).values_list('mk_id__marketplace', flat=True)
>>> print allmarketplaces
['Flipkart', 'Snapdeal']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for i in range(len(allmarketplaces)):
   print allmarketplaces[i]['mk_id__marketplace']
```